# How to refer to constructors and operators in dartdoc?

Tags: dart

The [Dart Language Tour](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) covers documentation comments, and says:

> Inside a documentation comment, the Dart compiler ignores all text unless it
>   is enclosed in brackets. Using brackets, you can refer to classes, methods, 
>   fields, top-level variables, functions, and parameters. The names in brackets 
>   are resolved in the lexical scope of the documented program element.

I potentially want to be able to refer to anything in scope, but I'm having trouble working out how to refer to named and unnamed constructors, and operators.

I created a test library with documentation comments:

```
/// # Thingy
/// 
/// Blah [GLOBAL] blah [function] blah [Thingy] blah [Thingy.property] blah
/// [Thingy.virtualProperty] blah [Thingy.named]  blah [Thingy.method]
/// blah [Thingy.operator+].
/// Try these: [Thingy.named()] blah [Thingy.()] blah [Thingy()].

library Thingy;

const int GLOBAL = 0;

void function(int arg) {}

/// A class.
/// 
/// Blah [GLOBAL] blah [function] blah [Thingy] blah [property] blah
/// [virtualProperty] blah [named] blah [method] blah [operator+].
/// Try these: [Thingy.named()] blah [Thingy.()] blah [Thingy()].
class Thingy {

  int property;

  int get virtualProperty => 0;
  set virtualProperty(int arg) {}

  Thingy(int arg) {}
  Thingy.named(int arg) {}

  /// A method.
  /// 
  /// Blah [GLOBAL] blah [function] blah [Thingy] blah [property] blah
  /// [virtualProperty] blah [named] blah [method] blah [operator+] blah
  /// [arg].
  /// Try these: [Thingy.named()] blah [Thingy.()] blah [Thingy()].
  void method(int arg) {}

  Thingy operator+(int arg) => null;
}
```

The library, class and method documentation generated by Dartdoc come out looking like:

> Blah [GLOBAL](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) blah [function blah](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) [Thingy](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) blah [property](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) blah
>   [virtualProperty](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) blah `named` blah [method](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#comments/) blah `operator+` ...
>
> Try these: `Thingy.named` blah `Thingy.()` blah `Thingy()`.

(Not actual Dartdoc output - just what it looks like. Dart language tour URL used to simulate the links.)

Most of the references work, but how can I refer to constructors and operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are referred to with `new`

```
/// [new MyClass] 
/// [new MyClass.someNamedConstructor]
```

I haven't found a way to reference operators

```
/// [operator ==] or [==] seem not to work
```

I created https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/1087

Comment: Yes, those worked. Thanks. Can you point me to where that is documented? Any clue as to how reference an operator implementation?

Comment: I don't know where this is documented. I'll try to find out. I think I saw it mentioned in bug reports or other discussions. Also the closurization of constructors works this way (`new MyClass#` not sure if this is fully available yet)

Answer (score 0):

[Effective Dart: Documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/effective-dart/documentation/) documents dart documentation comments, including references.

Comment: Thanks to the the Dartdoc team for pointing that out in response to Günter's bug report; and yes I am a bit embarrassed I didn't manage to find that before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is out of date.

Now, to reference the main unnamed constructor:

```
/// [MyClass.new]
```

And to reference a named constructor:

```
/// [MyClass.someNamedConstructor]
```

[This analyzer message](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=deprecated_new_in_comment_reference#deprecated_new_in_comment_reference) explains it.